# Having issue on adding data to Entity Framework table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Can you please let me know why I am not able to add data to `Region` table here?

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Region newRegion = new Region()
    {
        RegionID = 5000,
        RegionDescription = TextBox1.Text

    };

    db.Regions.Add(newRegion);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

at:

```
db.Regions.Add(newRegion);
```

I have a `Region` class as:

```
namespace EFDataStore
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Region
    {
        public int RegionID { get; set; }
        public string RegionDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have namespace conflict. You will need full namespace for Region class.

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newRegion = new EFDataStore.Region() <==== Need full namespace.
    {
        RegionID = 5000,
        RegionDescription = TextBox1.Text

    };

    db.Regions.Add(newRegion);
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```